# Zener Diode Identification/Replacement

Tags: diodes, identification, zener

I am seeing if I can trace out remake some circuit boards laying around.  For this particular board, I can identify all parts except this diode.

The part number is CK 2EZET (I am only assuming it is a zener based on the part number)
[image: Diode Picture]

I tried googling just part of the number and came up with this:
[2EZ Diode Series](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/info_redirect/datasheet/eic/2EZ68D5.pdf.shtml)

Even if I cannot find the exact part, can I use any zener diode with similar characteristics?  It is reverse biased across 28V Input and GND (This board controls a motor)

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a similar Zener:

- the same or higher power
- the same breakdown voltage

If you can't identify this diode, it would be a good idea to take it out and measure its breakdown voltage.

> It is reverse biased across 28V Input and GND

If this is what you mean:

[image]
Source: [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/zenereg2.html)

Then the breakdown voltage is V<sub>Z</sub>